# ExecuteScalar or Top 1

Tags: c#, sql

Which code is more optimal?

```
SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

in C# 
or

```
Top 1
```

in SQL?

I know, i could run tests, just though there might be someone with an answer in his pocket.

Thanks!

Edit: Assuming that there is only one column column being displayed.

Comment: What is your definition of optimal?

Comment: They are different things, they don't compare. They are not mutually exclusive or alternative answers to the same problem.

Comment: I wish I had the proper answer to this (you might have to test it yourself) but my money is on Top 1 because it is handled directly by the database. It might however be easier to use execute scalar since the C# code will expect one result rather than a list (which would only contain one element thanks to Top 1)

Comment: The two things don't seem interchangeable.

Comment: If you think this is a good question you are almost certainly doing somthing sub optimal. This means this is a bad question.

Comment: Well they are actually interchangeable depending on how you use them. Executescalar will return the first column of the first row that matches the condition, if your Top 1 query just grabs the first column in the result set, they can be used interchangeably.

Comment: For TOP 1 do you mean `ExecuteReader` where the command string is `SELECT TOP 1 ...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Obviously Select Top 1 is more optimized with respect to performance as it will be executed directly at the database server. But yet the comparison is not valid as both are different things.

Comment: So true... because SSMS Is somehow magically not a client that needs to fetch the data over the network and display the data to the user

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be optimal more than direct SQL code, but you should also find out which SQL code produces SQLCommand, DataContext or other stuff you use to communicate with database.